# Watson's Lemma to obtain first three terms

Tags: asymptotics

I am unsure how to proceed with the following question due to the fact I am unsure how to obtain a Taylor series for the following function.

Question:

Using Watson’s Lemma, obtain the first three terms in the asymptotic expansions as x → ∞ of
$$\int_0^{\pi/4}e^{-xt}(1+\cos t)^{\frac{1}{2}}dt$$

Currently I am taking $\phi(t) = (1+\cos t)^\frac{1}{2}$ with $\lambda = 0$ so $g(t) = (1+\cos t)^\frac{1}{2}$

I currently take the expansion to be $\sqrt{(1+\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n t^{2n}}{(2n)!}}$

Here I am unsure how to translate this expansion into the approximation $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^N a_n\frac{\Gamma(\lambda+n+1)}{x^{\lambda+n+1}}$

EDIT::
Going from what user254665 said. Does this seem correct?

letting $(1+cost)^{1/2} = \sqrt{2}cos\frac{t}{2} = \sqrt(2) \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(\frac{-1}{4})^kt^{2k}}{(2k)!}$

$f(x) \sim \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\Gamma(2n+1)}{x^{2n+1}}\frac{(\frac{-1}{4})^n}{(2n)!}$

$\Gamma(2n+1)$ cancels with $(2n)!$

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(\frac{-1}{4})^n}{x^{2n+1}}$

$n=0, \frac{1}{x}$

$n=1, \frac{-1}{4x^3}$

$n=2, \frac{1}{16x^5}$

Comment: My apologies, dt, will amend question

Comment: Why not put $(1+\cos t)^{1/2}=\sqrt 2 \cos t/2$ , as $(\exp a t)( \cos b t)$ is easily integrated.

Comment: Matt, user254665 meant $\sqrt{2}\cos(t/2)$, not $\sqrt{2}\cos(t)/2$ as you wrote.

Comment: Ah yes I see that now. I have amended my answer accordingly